# App crashing while sending location coordinates using fused location to an API

Tags: android, kotlin, geolocation, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines

i am creating an app that sends your location coordinates to a server using an API. I am using fused location client to get location coordinates and send them through API using retrofit. Here is the main activity.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var currentLocation: Location
    private lateinit var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    private lateinit var locationAPI: LocationAPI

    private var permissionCode = 101
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

        getCurrentLocationUser()
         locationAPI = RetrofitHelper().getInstance().create(LocationAPI::class.java)
    }
    private fun getCurrentLocationUser() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            !=(PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this , android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            !=(PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED))
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this , arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                , permissionCode)
            return
        }

        val getLocation = fusedLocationProviderClient.getCurrentLocation(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, object : CancellationToken() {
            override fun onCanceledRequested(p0: OnTokenCanceledListener) =
                CancellationTokenSource().token


            override fun isCancellationRequested() = false

        })

            getLocation.addOnSuccessListener { location ->

            if (location != null){
                currentLocation = location

                GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    val locResult = locationAPI.sendReq(PostReq("546HJHDSJS87384","1" ,
                        currentLocation.latitude.toString() , currentLocation.longitude.toString()
                        , Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString() ))
                    if (locResult != null){
                        withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                            Log.d("APIREQ" , locResult.body().toString())
                            tvText.text = locResult.message().toString()
                        }
                    } else {
                        withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                            Log.d("APIREQ" , locResult.body().toString())
                            tvText.text = locResult.message().toString()
                        }
                    }
                }
//                tvText.text = currentLocation.latitude.toString()+ "      " + currentLocation.longitude.toString()
//                Log.d("LocCord", currentLocation.latitude.toString() + currentLocation.longitude.toString())

            }
            else{
//              tvText.text = "null"
                Log.d("LocCord", "null")
            }

        }

    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        when(requestCode ){
            permissionCode -> if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                getCurrentLocationUser()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the class of api response that will come after API request is send

```
data class APIResponse(
    val `0`: PostReq,
    val `1`: PostReq,
    val message: String,
    val success: Boolean
)
```

Here is the data class where i am sending the body through post function of retrofit.

```
data class PostReq(
    val device_id: String,
    val id: String,
    val latitude: String,
    val longitude: String,
    val timestamp: String
)
```

This is the retrofit class where i created retrofit instance

```
class RetrofitHelper {

    val BASE_URL = "https://instapressfit.in/"

    fun getInstance() : Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }
}
```

This is the interface for the post request function which is a suspend function

```
interface LocationAPI {


    @POST("location.php")
    suspend fun sendReq(@Body postReq: PostReq) : Response<APIResponse>
}
```

Edit- here is the logcat. I am using on real device so there might be extra logs. Please ignore it. The log was too long so included the one it was after the crash

```
   2023-04-27 13:01:46.281 27919-28055 AndroidRuntime          com.example.mylocation               E  FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-2
                                                                                                        Process: com.example.mylocation, PID: 27919
                                                                                                        java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 1 path $
                                                                                                            at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextNonWhitespace(JsonReader.java:1401)
                                                                                                            at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:549)
                                                                                                            at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:425)
                                                                                                            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:207)
                                                                                                            at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:40)
                                                                                                            at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:27)
                                                                                                            at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:243)
                                                                                                            at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:153)
                                                                                                            at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:174)
                                                                                                            at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
                                                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
                                                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
                                                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
                                                                                                            Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@74a01a9, Dispatchers.IO]

Edit -> I have added okhttp client for logging intercepter. Here is the log. The data is sending 

2023-05-03 00:06:43.941 17402-17694 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.mylocation               I  --> POST https://instapressfit.in/location.php
2023-05-03 00:06:43.942 17402-17694 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.mylocation               I  Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
2023-05-03 00:06:43.942 17402-17694 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.mylocation               I  Content-Length: 126
2023-05-03 00:06:43.943 17402-17694 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.mylocation               I  {"device_id":"546HJHDSJS87384","id":"1","latitude":"28.6655143","longitude":"77.0815078","timestamp":"2023-05-03 00:06:43.88"}
2023-05-03 00:06:43.943 17402-17694 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.mylocation               I  --> END POST (126-byte body)
2023-05-03 00:06:45.495 17402-17694 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.mylocation               I  <-- 200 OK https://instapressfit.in/location.php (1552ms)
2023-05-03 00:06:45.495 17402-17694 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.mylocation               I  Date: Tue, 02 May 2023 18:36:46 GMT
2023-05-03 00:06:45.495 17402-17694 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.mylocation               I  Server: Apache
2023-05-03 00:06:45.495 17402-17694 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.mylocation               I  Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
2023-05-03 00:06:45.496 17402-17694 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.mylocation               I  Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
2023-05-03 00:06:45.496 17402-17694 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.mylocation               I  Pragma: no-cache
2023-05-03 00:06:45.496 17402-17694 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.mylocation               I  Vary: Accept-Encoding
2023-05-03 00:06:45.496 17402-17694 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.mylocation               I  Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=a6f35132763a5f7493b52678bc81486b; path=/
2023-05-03 00:06:45.496 17402-17694 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.mylocation               I  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 
2023-05-03 00:06:45.496 17402-17694 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.mylocation               I  Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
2023-05-03 00:06:45.496 17402-17694 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.mylocation               I  Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Accept
2023-05-03 00:06:45.496 17402-17694 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.mylocation               I  Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
2023-05-03 00:06:45.496 17402-17694 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.mylocation               I  Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
2023-05-03 00:06:45.496 17402-17694 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.mylocation               I  Connection: Keep-Alive
2023-05-03 00:06:45.496 17402-17694 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.mylocation               I  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
2023-05-03 00:06:45.496 17402-17694 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.mylocation               I  Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
2023-05-03 00:06:45.498 17402-17694 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.mylocation               I  <-- END HTTP (0-byte body)
```

Comment: If you're crashing, post the stack trace.

Comment: i have added after the crash part of log as it was above word limit

Comment: I think the error means that the api response is empty. Can you check that if it returns json or not? You can try using [logging interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor) with log type `BODY` to see the full response in logcat

Comment: i have added http loging logcat. Please check it